# How to call a method inside Execute method in Quartz.net Scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I am a beginner to Quartz.Net. I am trying to call a method from my quartz.net schedule job **excute** method. Can anyone help if this is the right way or is there any better approach available?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Tweet twts, HttpPostedFileBase imgFile) 
{
    UploadFile uploadFile = new UploadFile();
    bool isPosted = uploadFile.UploadFiles(twts, imgFile);      

    if(isPosted)
    {
        twts.tweets = "";
        ViewBag.Message = "Tweeted Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Tweet Post Unsuccessful";
    }

    return View("Tweets");
}
```

UploadFile.cs

```
public bool UploadFiles(Tweet twts, HttpPostedFileBase imgFile)
{
    string key = Utils.Twitterkey;
    string secret = Utils.Twittersecret;
    string token = Utils.Twittertoken; 
    string tokenSecret = Utils.TwittertokenSecret;

    string message = twts.tweets;

    string filePath; string imagePath = "";

    HttpPostedFileBase filebase =
        new HttpPostedFileWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["imgFile"]);

    if (imgFile == null)
    {
        imgFile = filebase;
    }

    if (imgFile.FileName != "")
    {

        filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/");

        if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        }

        filePath = filePath + Path.GetFileName(imgFile.FileName);
        imgFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        imagePath = 
            Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Images/"), filePath);
    }
            //Enter the Image Path if you want to upload image.

    var service = new TweetSharp.TwitterService(key, secret);
    service.AuthenticateWith(token, tokenSecret);

    //this Condition  will check weather you want to upload a image & text or only text 
    if (imagePath.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var result = service.SendTweetWithMedia(
                new SendTweetWithMediaOptions
                {
                    Status = message,
                    Images = new Dictionary<string, Stream> { { "sos", stream } }
                });
        }
    }
    else // just message
    {
        var result = service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions
        {
            Status = message
        });
    }

    return true;
}
```

JobScheduler.cs

```
public class JobScheduler<IDGJob>
        where IDGJob : Quartz.IJob
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler().Result;
        scheduler.Start();
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<IDGJob>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("IDGJob", "IDG")
            .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 1/1 * ? *") 
            .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
            .WithPriority(1)
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

IDGJob.cs

```
public class IDGJob : IJob
{
    Action<Tweet, HttpPostedFileBase> upFile;

    public IDGJob(Action<Tweet, HttpPostedFileBase> UploadFiles)
    {
        if (UploadFiles == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(UploadFiles));
        }

        Action<Tweet, HttpPostedFileBase> upFile = UploadFiles;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        upFile(twts, imgFile); ****
    }
}
```

Based on the below answer I updated this class.
**** Throws Error "The twts does not exist in the current context".. of course it will, but my question how to pass the value from the above flow?

Answer (score 1):

Your `IDGJob` type should take a callback and invoke it inside `Execute()`

```
public class IDGJob : IJob
{
    Action callback;

    public IDGJob(Action action)
    {
        if(action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

        callback = action;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Now the code using this class can provide a callback when it constructs an object and have it do whatever is needed.

Alternatively, you can expose an event `Executed` and bind handlers in the client code.

```
public class IDGJob : IJob
{
    public event EventHandler Executed;

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Executed?.(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In this version, client code would `+=` on `Executed`.

Comment: Could you please suggest what I missed in the IDGJob.class

Comment: suggest what he missed in the IDGJob.class ?